# Headroom и UIKit - как связать

Tags: javascript, uikit

Использую на сайте скрипт для скрытия навигации headroom.js, также на странице есть блоки, которое "прилипает" вверху страницы - реализовано через uk-sticky (UIKit). Необходимо,  чтобы при прокрутке вниз, при появлении меню, меню сдвигало блоки, если они встречаются?

https://github.com/Alex-Indilex/Headroom-and-UIkit

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добавил ссылку на файлы